# b64 Encryption - Decryption with SMX to PHP

Tags: php, encryption, base64

### **Base64 Encryption (SMX) - Decryption (PHP)**

I have been trying to decrypt a string in PHP that was originally encrypted and decoded in a language called [SMX (server Macro Expansion).](http://www.smxlang.org/docs/) I have tried numerous methods to go about this but none seem to work. I have tried various configurations of mcrypt_decrypt() as well as other functions I found online. The [encryption](http://www.smxlang.org/docs/?group=&func=encrypt#) in SMX uses Base64 with DES (i think) by default. I have gotten to the point to where I am actually looking into the source code for SMX that is on [Google SVN](http://code.google.com/p/smx/source/browse/trunk/libsmx/open-enc.cpp?r=459) and I have emailed the project overseer.

Below is a sample of the code I have in SMX that [encrypts](http://www.smxlang.org/docs/?group=&func=encrypt#) and then encodes the string properly....

```
%gset(string_var,%encode(%encrypt(%string%,passkey)))
```

Then below this is the code that I have tried so far in PHP...

```
$string = $_GET["string"];
$decoded_string = base64_decode($string);
//$decrypt_string = decrypt($string, "passkey");
$decrypt_string = decrypt2($string, "passkey");

function decrypt($string, $key)
{
  $result = '';
  $string = base64_decode($string);

  for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
    $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
    $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
    $char = chr(ord($char)-ord($keychar));
    $result.=$char;
  }

  return $result;
}

function decrypt2($sStr, $sKey)
{
    $decrypted= mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_DES,
        $sKey,
        base64_decode($sStr),
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECBs
    );
        echo " decrypted = " . $decrypted;
echo "<br><br>";
    $dec_s = strlen($decrypted);
    echo " dec_s = " . $dec_s;
echo "<br><br>";
    $padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s-1]);
    echo " padding = " . $padding;
echo "<br><br>";
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);
    echo " decrypted = " . $decrypted;
echo "<br><br>";
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you keep reading the source code and try to emulate the process line by line.  For us to figure this out we would have to do the exact same research you have done to even understand what is happening.

Comment: `decrypt2` seems to be on the money. The question is how the password is transformed to a key, and if DES is indeed the correct method. Note that the SMX encrypt "macro" seems to be a perfect example on how *not* to perform encryption. Actually, it looks like a perfect copy of the `mcrypt_encrypt()` example code before it got replaced by my code...

Comment: Well that makes me feel a little better. Yeah, SMX is well... :-( I am in the process of replacing it for many reasons, but the encryption is just one. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: In the SMX source code, I believe, there is a cipher that is created and uses [EVP_BytesToKey()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) in ... [open-enc.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/smx/source/browse/trunk/libsmx/open-enc.cpp?r=459), line 103 function.

Comment: @CommonKnowledge interesting, there is absolutely nothing about this in the description, and I don't see any salt pre-pended. But maybe that depends on the key input...